# Running 2 functions in Processing

Tags: function, processing

I can't seem to run 2 functions in succession. Only the first function is executed. When I comment one of those 2 functions, the sketch works fine.

Here's the complete code:

```
float angle1, angle2;

void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw()
{
  background(64);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  circle1();
  circle2();
}

void circle1()
{
  stroke(200, 0, 0);
  rotate(radians(angle1));
  for(int i = 0; i < 360; i += 5)
  {
    rotate(radians(5));
    bezier(0, 0, -50, -50, -50, -150, 0, -200);
  }
  angle1 -= 1;
}

void circle2()
{
  stroke(0, 200, 0);
  rotate(radians(angle2));
  for(int i = 360; i > 0; i -= 5)
  {
   rotate(radians(-5));
   bezier(0, 0, 50, -50, 50, -150, 0, -200);
  }
  angle2 += 1;
}
```

Why does it behave like so?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is actually working, the issue is you're using a single/global coordinate system and when you call `rotate()` in `circle1()` you rotate **the whole sketch** in one direction, then in `circle2()` you rotate everything in the opposite direction (therefore cancelling out the rotation)

You should have a look at [pushMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) and [popMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html),but especially the [2D Transformations tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/)

[image: rotated grid]

In short, using `pushMatrix()` starts isolating a coordinate system and `popMatrix()` reverts to the previous coordinate system. This way, your rotations wouldn't interfere with each other:

```
float angle1, angle2;

void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw()
{
  background(64);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  circle1();
  circle2();
}

void circle1()
{
  pushMatrix();
  stroke(200, 0, 0);
  rotate(radians(angle1));
  for(int i = 0; i < 360; i += 5)
  {
    rotate(radians(5));
    bezier(0, 0, -50, -50, -50, -150, 0, -200);
  }
  angle1 -= 1;
  popMatrix();
}

void circle2()
{
  pushMatrix();
  stroke(0, 200, 0);
  rotate(radians(angle2));
  for(int i = 360; i > 0; i -= 5)
  {
   rotate(radians(-5));
   bezier(0, 0, 50, -50, 50, -150, 0, -200);
  }
  angle2 += 1;
  popMatrix();
}
```

Also, keep in mind you call `rotate(radians(5))` and `rotate(radians(-5))` and you might want to use `angle1` and `angle2` in the `radians()` calls

Comment: Thank you so much for your concise explanation!